# “Cannot call a class as a function” react native in non component class

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Crawler.js:

```
export class WebCrawler {
    cookie_stores = [CookieStore(sisgrad_domain)];
...
```

App.js:

```
import { WebCrawler } from './crawler.js';

var MyCrawler = new WebCrawler();

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
...
```

But I'm getting “Cannot call a class as a function”. I've found multiple answers about this error. Some of them tell to use `new` before the class name, which is what I'm doing, and the others say I must extend `Component`. But my `Crawler` class does nothing on the UI, why should I extend `Component`?

Comment: Might import `WebCrawler` ?

Comment: @JonasW. i've edited, the name was wrong. But good eyes, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `CookieStore` is a class too, so you need to do

```
  new CookieStore
```